# Rails crash (Exception `Errno::EPIPE' - Broken pipe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pipe, webrick, broken-pipe, epipe

I my Rails servers crashes few times a day and I don't know what is the reason. This is what I get in logs when debug mode is turned on:

```
[19/Aug/2013 11:28:50] "GET /apps/guess-the-model?q=pending HTTP/1.1" 200 - 141.0851
Exception `Errno::EPIPE' at /home/ciembor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpresponse.rb:396 - Broken pipe
Killed
```

Anyone met this problem?

Comment: are you using webrick in production or as a personal dev box?

Comment: This is my dev box, but I'm not sure yet what's on production.